# Allow only 1 ip to connect mssql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, ip

i have a mssql server 2008 installed server. I want to connect only from my home pc (static ip) no one can connect with their machines.

i have done to allow only my ip to connect the ftp but i cant find the way to connect with my static ip to mssql server 2008

how can i do it? is it a firewall setting or is it a setting from sql server 2008?

i will be very appriciated if someone can help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use [IPSEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb531150) on windows machine ( the server ) to limit the connection it allows ( including specific ports ).

Check this out, it might help you [Restrict IP Address to prevent invalid login attack to SQL Server.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/04/10/572605.aspx)